# Verify safety of Java classes compiled from Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

**Background**

I am assisting in the building of a web based interface to program simple AI, which play games and compete against other AI.

One of the main requirements of the system is that user submitted code is verified to be safe to run on the server. 
I.e, if the submitted code accesses the file system, we need to reject the submission.

Currently, the system runs using Java as a submission language, and performs byte-code analysis to check classes used by the submitted code against a white-list. If the submission uses classes which are not allowed, the submission is rejected.

I am currently exploring our options for supporting submissions in Python, which (using the Jython library) are converted into a Java class that runs against the existing system.

I have run into some issues, which involve the Java-compiled Python code. Namely, a simple Python script (once compiled to Java), doing no more than variable assignments appears to use the same classes as a Python class that reads and writes files. This means that I can't tell (based on classes used) whether or not the file system will be accessed.

**Questions**

Does the compilation of Python code into a Java object using the Jython libraries simply wrap the code into a class that calls a Python interpreter and executes the Python code? (If so, byte code analysis is not the solution to the problem explained above).

If the Jython libraries do actually create a true Java object, that doesn't call a Python interpreter when running, how can I analyse whether or not the object is attempting to access the file system?

Comment: `System.setSecurityManager();`

Comment: General experience in the CPython world is that sandboxing Python is damn near impossible, and a static analysis based approach in particular is not even remotely useful. For example, many tried and failed to find a method to prevent programs from accessing certain functions. Some of the hacks are implementation specific but others could reasonably work in Jython, regardless of whether it's a "true Java object" because they just use Python semantics. See https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-November/130132.html for a long and comprehensive discussion.

Comment: @delnan I am well aware of the issues with sandboxing Python, which is why I was hoping to get an answer as to whether or not Jython runs compiled classes via an interpreter. If this is the case (and if I can't get an answer), I will likely be looking towards parsing ASTs generated from the user's input Python code, and seeing if that would be a viable solution to finding out if submitted code performs un-safe actions.

Comment: @user3289415 Your plan to analyze the AST strongly suggests that you *don't* understand how hard sandboxing Python is.

Comment: I am aware of issues such as the following code:
[x for x in ().__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__() if  x.__name__ == 'file'][ 0]("testing.txt", "r")

working in the same manner as open("testing.txt","r"). Do you not think that analysing the AST will be able give the desired results?

Comment: @user3289415 No, I don't think at all AST analysis will be sufficient, precisely because there are countless issues like that and handling even the subset I know of requires prohibiting so many things that virtually no legitimate Python program more complex than simple arithmetic is allowed. Just use OS level sandboxing and resource limitations, it's also language agnostic and can also add some useful restrictions (time taken, memory consumed) to the Java version.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Jython the same language as Python?
>
> Yes. Jython is an implementation of the Python language for the Java
>   platform. Jython 2.5 implements the same language as CPython 2.5, and
>   nearly all of the Core Python standard library modules. (CPython is
>   the C implementation of the Python language.) Jython 2.5 uses the same
>   regression test suite as CPython, with some minor modifications.

https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo

So no need to worry about calling external python interpreter.

To solve problems with code checking, you can try this http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/the-java-sandbox.html
Documentation has good samples of how to use it http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/java-sandbox-03-documentation.html

Comment: That FAQ entry is about user-visible behavior. In contrast, OP is very much concerned with implementation details.

Comment: Well, if you find the place in Jython where it executes external native Python interpreter to run your code - I'll send you a beer, I swear.

Comment: I don't know what the answer to OP's question is, I'm just pointing out that the text you quote doesn't settle it. Note that "a Python interpreter" need not be an *external* Python interpreter (e.g. an embedded CPython).

Comment: I personally used Jython on non-x86 machines, which have only Java runtime, this will be enough?

Comment: No, since a Python interpreter in Java is squarely in the realm of possibility (even more when you consider the sliding scale between full-on compilation and interpretation). Let's say some Jython code is accessing the Java class `EvilFactory` for its nefarious purposes: Will the bytecode output by Jython contain references to that class in the same way it would for equivalent Java code? Or will it just be a impenetrable mess that makes no mention of `EvilFactory` but accesses it at run time via reflection?

Comment: Just decompile some class, generated by Jython and see. As far as I know it will be same references.